# WMI Query to determine DNS Servers without null entries

Tags: wmi

I can use the following WMI query to determine any DNS servers my machine might be using:

```
SELECT DNSServerSearchOrder
FROM Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration
```

However, the following query I wrote to ignore null entries is invalid and I don't know why:

```
SELECT DNSServerSearchOrder
FROM Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration
WHERE DNSServerSearchOrder!=null
```

Is there a way to filter out the null entries?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The WQL language [supports](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394605%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) `!=` and the `IS [NOT] NULL` syntax, the problem is the property which you choose `DNSServerSearchOrder` is an array, and [you can't use an array property in a WQL Where sentence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa392902%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). So the workaround is use another property of the [`Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394217%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) WMI class in the where condition.

Answer (score 1):

Just use this

```
WHERE IPEnabled=True
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an older post, but I needed this information myself today, from Powershell to list out the IP addresses used as DNS servers on a system:

```
Get-WmiObject -Namespace root\cimv2 -Query "Select dnsserversearchorder from win32_networkadapterconfiguration" | where {$_.DNSServerSEarchOrder -ne $null} | select -ExpandProperty DNSServerSearchOrder
```

This results in a simple array of the IP addresses which can be used further in Powershell, either by sending to a variable or by piping through to another command.

Comment: This works EXACTLY how it should.  Thank you.  Trying to get the DNS to pipe over to a WSL2 instance automatically.

Answer (score 0):

In PowerShell v3+:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration | Select-Object -ExpandProperty DNSServerSearchOrder
```

Due to the way `-ExpandProperty` works, null (missing) entries will be omitted incidentally.

Answer (score -1):

Are you looking for this instead:

```
SELECT DNSServerSearchOrder
FROM Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration
WHERE DNSServerSearchOrder IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: That also appears to be invalid, did you try it in Powershell?

Comment: No, just valid SQL -- are you using this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394605(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: As far as I know, the syntax SHOULD be correct since "SELECT DHCPServer FROM Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration WHERE DHCPServer!=null" is valid.