# How to determine if a server is only accessible using IPv6

Tags: delphi, dns, indy10

Using Delphi 7 with Indy10, I need to create an IPv6 to IPv4 proxy for a service that doesn't support IPv6.  I can manage that fine.  The only issue I'm facing is, if they enter a domain name rather than an IP address, how can I determine if the destination server is only accessible via IPv6 and not IPv4?  If IPv4 is available, I would prefer to send the request directly rather than going through the proxy.

Is using TIdDNSResolver the only solution?

I found code for with 2 functions for using it, one returning an IPv4 and the other an IPv6 address. Presumably the IPv4 function will return nothing if there is only IPv6 available.

But the functions both require a DNS server to be specified.  How am I to find one?  Is there some way to use the default DNS server to find the IP addresses, perhaps using a Windows API and not Indy?

Answer (score 1):

You actually have several questions in your question. I will answer  this one: "How do I find a DNS server address?".

One answer is: call [GetAdaptersAddresses](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iphlpapi/nf-iphlpapi-getadaptersaddresses) in the IpHelper API. This call will return many addresses including the DNS address. In the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iphlpapi/nf-iphlpapi-getadaptersaddresses) there is a C++ example you can translate to Delphi.

Another answer is to use command line `IPCONFIG /ALL`. In the output, you'll find the DNS address.

A third answer is to use a WMI query. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16804412/wmi-query-to-determine-dns-servers-without-null-entries).

Comment: Actually, I was thinking about this and I think the service will support a domain name pointing to an IPv6 address, since winsock will take care of everything.  I think what it doesn't support is specifying an IPv6 address directly in the URL using the square brackets syntax, as the service doesn't know what to do with that.  I tried to quote an example URL with spare brackets but the forum won't let me.  I need to test this theory using a Windows hosts file.  If that is the case, I can simply detect a square bracket and pass the URL to my proxy server.

Comment: What is wrong with IPv6 URL? Example: `http://[1080:0:0:0:8:800:200C:417A]/index.html`

Comment: An HTTP browser/client is not supposed to transmit the brackets themselves. It should recognize the brackets and extract the IPv6 address before using it. Given a URL like `http://[1080:0:0:0:8:800:200C:417A]/index.html`, it would connect to `1080:0:0:0:8:800:200C:417A` on port 80 and then request `/index.html`. Just as `http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/index.html` would connect to `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` for IPv4.

Comment: This is yet another question. StackOverflow rules do not permit that. You have to create a new question specific with this problem.